# Sorting char arrays by swapping pointers, C++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort an array of char pointers (char * _string) by swapping pointers.

I have this method, and what I want to do is use the values I get from _string and sort them by not manipulating _string, but the empty helper array (char * _output) which I also hand over to the method.

Can anyone help me and tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
void sortAsc(char* _string, char* _output) 
{

    int length = strlen(_string);

        // output and string now point to the same area in the memory
    _output = _string; 

    for( int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          for( int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                if( *(_output) > (_output[j] ) ) {

                    // save the pointer
                    char* tmp = _output;

                    // now output points to the smaller value   
                    _output = _output+j; 

                    // move up the pointer to the smaller value
                    _output + j; 

                    // now the pointer of the smaller value points to the higher value
                    _output = tmp; 

                    // move down to where we were + 1
                    _output - j + 1; 

            }
        }
    }

    //_output[length]='\0';

    //delete chars;
 }
```

In my main-Method, I do something like this:

```
char * string = {"bcdae"};
char * output = new char[5];
sortAsc(string, output);
```

After that code, I want the output array to contain the sorted values.

Comment: What's wrong with it at the moment? Give us some sample input and output or errors that you're getting.

Comment: After `_output = _string` you will lose any reference to the helper array you passed to the function, surely this doesn't help.

Comment: Well after compiling the output variable should be "abcde".
At this point, the program doesn't throw any errors, but the output variable is simply still empty after calling the method.

Comment: `_output + j;` does not what you want (and similar `_output - j + 1`)

Comment: Can you use std::vector<char>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's do the selection sort for a 10 size int array using pointer notation, you can simply change it to an array list.

```
      *---*---*---*---*---* ........
a[] = | 1 | 2 | 4 | 0 | 3 | ........
      *---*---*---*---*---* ........
        ^--------We start here looking for the smaller numbers and sort the array.


for( i = 0; i < 10; i++ ){
    k = i;
    bypass = *( a + i );
    for( j = i + 1; j < 10; j++ ){

        /* To get Increasing order. */
        if( bypass > *( a + j ) ){
           bypass = *( a + j );
           k = j;
        }
    }
    if ( k != i ){
         *( a + k ) = *( a + i );
         *( a + i ) = bypass;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sorts the string into an already allocated buffer, and if the buffer isn't large enough tells you how big it has to be:

```
std::size_t sortAsc(char const* string, char* dest, std::size_t dest_length) {
  std::size_t str_length = strlen(string);
  char const* str_end = string + str_length;
  if (dest_length < str_length+1)
    return str_length+1;
  std::copy( string, str_end, output );
  output[str_length] = '\0';
  std::sort( output, output+strlen(output) );
  return str_length+1;
}
```

This does the poor "allocate a new string" pattern, using the above implementation:

```
char* allocate_and_sortAsc(char const* string) {
  std::size_t str_length = strlen(string);
  char* retval = new char[str_length+1];
  std::size_t count = sortAsc( string, retval, str_length+1);
  ASSERT( count <= str_length );
  return retval;
}
```

And don't use variable names that start with an `_`, it is a bad practice because it wanders really near compiler reserved names.  `_Capital` is reserved everywhere, and `_lower` in global scope, and `foo__bar` everywhere.

Comment: @Abhishek No, I won't remove the "set the last character of a buffer to `'\0'`", buffer overflow/failure to properly terminate is one of the most common kinds of critical security errors in C code.

Comment: @oluies why are you approving edits in C++ code?  Your profile does not show C++ expertise at the very least.